# Running Matlab application (.exe) from VBA (process does not finish)

Tags: vba, matlab, executable

I compiled a MatLab code to executable application to be ran from the VBA. When I run the application outside the VBA, everything is OK, but when I execute it through the VBA, it seems the last part of the MatLab code (which is data export) doesn't execute. Anyone had a similar experience or something that might help please?

Below is the basic VBA code I am using to run the application

```
Sub Run_EXE()

CurrentPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
Dim varProc As Variant
Dim strProgramName As String
    strProgramName = CurrentPath & "\Models\Master_Model_T1.exe"
    
varProc = Shell(strProgramName, 1)

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you mean that the exe starts but does not finish its `job` because of VBA? It would be, at least, strange... If so, should it be run with some administrative privileges/permissions? Did you try an automation from other application?

Comment: Yes, it runs but i can see it doesn't export the data to excel. Both the application and output excel file don't require any admin permissions, which is strange yes. Don't have any other application to test. (Edit; I tried executing it through batch, same problem), probably a compilation issue?

Comment: Just to prove that is even more weird...  How can you be sure that the exe is open? Does it have a window and you can see it? If you double click it, does it run as you need?

Comment: doesn't have any windows, just click and runs, I wrote in the code an output graph right before the exports, that how I know it runs (the graph shows up), then I see the excel file updating (when ran directly)

Comment: In which code did you write the output graph? In VBA or inside the exe application? If in VBA, this does not prove that the the exe runs... Please, also try: `CreateObject("WScript.Shell").exec (strProgramName)`. Are there spaces in the full name string?

Comment: nothing changed, I wrote the output graphs in matlab before compilation, now I just added another one after the export, and it shows when executed. So the code executes to the end, though it doesn't export the data as required when using automation. WEIRD (No spaces in string name)

Comment: What value get 'varProc' after using 'Shell'? Place a BreakPoint on the last lline ('End Sub').

Comment: Does your matlab script make any assumptions about the "current directory"?  That may differ between running the script manually and running it from Excel...

Comment: Yes, I accounted for that, the directories are dynamic, so wherever are the folders located, they get redirected to with current paths and pwd.

Comment: Hi Rayan Bared, I'm having exactly the same problem. Have you gotten it working in the meantime? If so, what was the solution? Regards, Benny